# Pre receive hook with non bare remote repo

Tags: python, git, githooks

I'm writing a pre-receive hook in a particular situation.
My remote repo is non bare (I know it's not recommended).

I want to check if the pushed files (from other repo) have been modified in the the remote one, so I wrote a Python script but I have the following problem:

I use `sh.git('ls-files', '-m')` but I can't understand why the output of this command is different if I execute it in the terminal.
In the script, It seems that the output is the same of `git ls-files` without the `-m` option.